# media queries on screen drag / resize not working

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a really basic question with regards to media queries

I have set up some sites which work fine in displaying content with different layouts called via media queries, however on viewing them on desktop and resizing the screen the media query doesnt get called. Any pointers on where I am going wrong?

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>

        <style>
            div{
                background:red;
                width:600px;
                height:200px;
            }
            @media (min-width: 61px AND max-width: 600px) {
div {
               background:green;
}
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div>Something</div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Above edited in line with @spaceBeers comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div {
  background:red;
  width:600px;
  height:200px;

  @media screen and (min-width: 61px) and (max-width: 600px) {
     background:green;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/5NzrW/

Your media query was outside the selector for the div. As far as things were concerned you were outputting the following:

```
div {
    background:red;
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
}

background:green;
```

So background: green was just on it's own. Replace your code with the example at the top and it should be fine.

Comment: Hi thanks, that was a really silly mistake, however it has not solved the problem, on chrome if I resize the window the div colour does not change...

Comment: Sorry, you missed screen out of the MQ. Have amended the answer and added a FSFiddle.